# PyQt5, создание окна в потоке

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть приложение (консольное) в нем есть бесконечный цикл, также мне нужно визуальное отображение некоторой информации из этого цикла.
То есть создать окно в которое все это будет выводиться, но проблема в том что при  создании окна , часть кода следующая за ним не работает пока окно не завершит свою работу.
Даже в потоке.

Это конструктор моего основного класса

```
    def __init__(self):
        message_window_thread = MessageWindowThread()
        message_window_thread.start()
        self.start()
```

После запуска потока, функция start() не срабатывает, и я не знаю почему, вот код класса потока

```
class MessageWindowThread(QThread):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs, ):
    super(MessageWindowThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.run()

def run(self):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
    window = Message()
    window.resize(100, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Само окно запускается.

Comment: Окна должны создаваться и работать в главном потоке. Бесконечный цикл можно отправить в отдельный поток, чтобы работал главный. Либо в цикле можно вызывать QApplication::processEvents, чтобы успевать обработать события из цикла обработки событий, чтобы интерфейс не зависал. Либо вместо цикла использовать QTimer

Comment: если вам действительно нужна помощь, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему.